# Convergence of a power series on specified interval

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

I am considering the power series $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k}$$
 and its convergence.
I checked easily by Ratio test that it converges absolutely for $|x| < 1$ and I check the endpoints $-1,1$. In the first case I got $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k}$ which converges, but not absolutely. For the other case, we have the divergent harmonic series. So actually my series converges on $[-1,1)$.

For uniform convergence is it true that it converges uniformly in $[-s,s]$ for $s \in [0,1)$ but not on $(-1,1)$ because at $-1,1$ we did not have absolute convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At $1$ it diverges and therefore it could not possibly converg uniformly on any set to which $1$ belongs.

And there is no connection between uniform convergence and absolute convergense. It converges uniformly on $[-s,s]$ by the Weierstrass $M$-test. In fact, it converges uniformly on any set of the form $[-1,s]$, with $0<s<1$, by [Dirichlet's test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_Test_for_Uniform_Convergence).

Comment: Ok for $1$ it makes sense. Using the M-test what series should I compare this to?

Comment: @mandella You should compare it to $\frac{s^n}n$.

Comment: And this one will converge because of the ratio test since $|s| < 1$ correct?

Comment: @mandella Indeed.

Comment: One more question, in $(-1,1)$ we do not include $1$ so why the convergence is not uniform again?

Comment: @mandella Because bounded functions never converge uniformly to an unbounded function.